# design from ltr to rtl automatically

Tags: translation, right-to-left, hebrew, left-to-right

I have a French website that is in LFR (Left to Right)
And the client is wanting to translate the site in hebrew thus transforming it to RTL (Right to Left). In all Hebrew Website the design is reversed

https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/

https://www.google.co.il/

Is there a way to do this automatically ? Again I am not talking about the text direction. I want to flip it horizontally the design, like a mirror effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mileage may vary. Some web page generation tools support RTL with easy switch, while with others the WYSIWYG breaks completely when you specify `<html dir="rtl">`. Browser fragmentation may also be an issue: some browser simply don't support RTL bulleted lists correctly.

There are quite a few good tutorials on the Web; I would recommend https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/09/building-rtl-aware-web-apps-and-websites-part-1/ and https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/10/building-rtl-aware-web-apps-websites-part-2/. If you look up Google to search for more articles, please remember that this field is quickly changing, and some recipes of few years ago may be obsolete.

You may find the automation with [css-flip](https://github.com/twitter/css-flip) or [rtlcss](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/rtlcss) useful.

Note that localization is generally not easy, and invariably requires a manual touch. You must understand the *target* culture very well to recognize tiny glitches that may look awful to the end-user. For example, on Hebrew Website you need different image for the "back" button. On Arabic sites, some numbers should be represented by indic digits, but other numbers are expected to use the usual digits.

Issues of first day of week, etc. are common for LTR localizations, too.